# How to characterize open sets in the unit circle

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers, open-map

At the end of the second chapter of Munkres' "Topology" there are some supplementary exercises concerning topological groups. One such group is $(S^1, \cdot)$. My problem is that the unit circle has not been dealt with so far in the theory and hence all I can assume is that it possesses the subspace topology it inherits from the metric topology of the complex plane. However, this does not seem to be enough to **easily** characterize the opens sets in $S^1$. Therefore I have turned to the site's help but I have only found answers relying on the notion of opennes of the map $x \mapsto e^{ix}$ which I only know how to be proved using compacteness preservation under a continuous function, **which has not been yet introduced in Munkres at this stage**.

My question is then if there is any other way around that does only use concepts and tools up to Munkres' "Topology" second chapter.

---

As always, any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: take $S^1=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^2 : \lVert v \rVert = 1\}$. the parameterizations $x\mapsto (x,\pm \sqrt{1-x^2})$ and $x\mapsto (\pm\sqrt{1-x^2},x)$ are homeomorphisms from $(-1,1)$ into a hemisphere of $S^1$. now any open set of $S^1$ is a union of the images of some open subsets of $(-1,1)$ via the above parameterizations

Comment: alternatively, the subspace topology does give a nice characterization of open subsets of $S^1$. to see why, when considering the intersection of an open ball with $S^1$, we get an arc. the arcs in $S^1$ form a basis for the topology on $S^1$

Comment: @CSquared Thank you for your comments! About your last one, I have convinced myself geometrically that it must be as you say, however how does one show it rigorously?

Comment: But you know the map $p : \mathbb R  \to S^1, p(x) = e^{ix}$, and understand that for each open interval $a,b)$  the set $S(a,b) = p((a,b))$ is a circular arc on $S^1$?

Comment: an arc in $S^1$ can be seen as the image of any open interval under the map $x\mapsto (\cos x, \sin x)\equiv e^{ix}$. showing that this is an open map will make rigorous my comment about arcs. showing it’s an open map can be viewed as a geometry problem

Comment: @CSquared I understand what you say, the problem is that I can not use geometrical tools in the environment of Munkres’ Topology.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I understand that, also I have viewed your proof of that map being open. However it uses compactness and at this stage it is a notion I shouldn’t have.

Comment: @MatteoMenghini using coordinate geometry and algebraic manipulations would be acceptable for munkres in terms of rigor imo. otherwise, use the fact that $f_{\pm}:(0,2\pi)\to S^1\setminus\{(\pm 1,0)\}$ given by $$f_+(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$$ $$f_-(x)=(\cos(\pi - x), \sin(x))$$ are homeomorphisms, hence open maps.

Comment: @MatteoMenghini I gave a proof without using compactness,  but it is fairly cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p :\mathbb R \to S^1, p(x) = e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$. This map is well-known to be a continuous surjective group homomorphism from $(\mathbb R,+)$ to $(S^1,\cdot)$.

We shall show that the set of circle segments
$$\mathfrak S = \{ S(a,b) = p((a,b)) \mid  (a,b) \in \mathfrak I \}$$
(where $\mathfrak I$ denotes the set of open intervals in $\mathbb R$) forms a basis for the topology on $S^1$.

Note that if $b -a > 2\pi$, then $S(a,b) = S^1$, and if $b - a \le 2\pi$, then $S(a,b)$ is the circle segment between $p(a)$ and $p(b)$ (where we travel counterclockwise; observe that $p(a) = p(b)$ in case $b -a = 2\pi$).

Trivially $S(a',b') \subset S(a,b)$ if $(a',b') \subset (a,b)$.

We have to show that the $S(a,b)$ are open in $S^1$ and form a basis.

1. The sets $S(-r,r)$ with $0 < r \le \pi/2$ are open in $S^1$ and form a neighborhood basis of the point $1 \in S^1$.

Consider the projection $\phi : S^1_+ = \{ z \in S^1 \mid \operatorname{Re} z > 0\} \to (-1,1), \phi(z) = \operatorname{Im} z$. This is a homeomorphism with inverse $\phi^{-1}(t) = \sqrt{1-t^2} + it$. We have $\phi(S(-r,r)) = \{\phi(p(x)) \mid x \in (-r,r) \} = \{\sin x \mid x \in (-r,r) \} = \sin((-r,r))$. Since $\sin$  maps $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ homeomorphically onto $(-1,1)$, we see that $\sin((-r,r))$ is open in $(-1,1)$, thus $S(-r,r)$ is open in $S^1_+$ and therefore open in $S^1$.

Now let $U \subset S^1$ be an open neighborhood of $1$ in $S^1$. Write $U = V \cap S^1$ with some open $V \subset \mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C$. Choose $s \in (0,1]$ such that $(1-s,1+s) \times (-s,s) \subset V$ and let $U_s = ((1-s,1+s) \times (-s,s)) \cap S^1$. This is an open neighborhood of $1$ in $S^1$ which is contained in $U$. Let $r \in (0,\pi/2]$ be the unique point such that $\sin r = s$. We have $\phi(U_S) = (-s,s) = \sin((-r,r)) = \phi(S(-r,r))$, thus $U_s =S(-r,r)$. This shows $0 \in S(-r,r) \subset U$.

2. The sets $S(c-r,c+r)$ with $r \in (0, \pi/2]$ are open in $S^1$ and form a neighborhood basis of the point $p(c) \in S^1$.

For each $z \in S^1$ the multiplication map $\mu_z : S^1 \to S^1, \mu_z(w) = z \cdot w$, is a homeomorphism (with inverse $\mu_z^{-1} = \mu_{z^{-1}})$. If $z = p(c)$, then
$$\mu_z(S(a,b)) = \{p(c) \cdot p(x) \mid x \in(a,b)\} = \{p(c + x) \mid x \in (a,b)\} = p((c+a,c+b)) = S(c+a,c+b) .$$

For each $z \in S^1$ we have $\mu_z(1) = z$ and therefore the sets $\mu_z(S(-r,r))$ are open and form a neighborhood basis of the point $z$. With $z = p(c)$ we therefore see that the sets $S(c-r,c+r)$ with $r \in (0,\pi/2]$,  are open and form a neighborhood basis of the point $z$.

3. All $S(a,b)$ are open (using 2. and the surjectivity of $p$ this shows that $\mathfrak S$ forms a basis for the topology on $S^1$).

Let $z \in S(a,b)$. Write $z = p(c)$ with $c \in (a,b)$ and choose $r \in (0,\pi/2]$ such that $(c-r,c+r) \subset (a,b)$. Then $z \in S(c-r,c+r) \subset S(a,b)$.